# write.csv with with sys.time in file name

Tags: r

I need to generate many csv files a day and story in a folder with the process time in the file name.

I tried to append the system time to the file name but was not able to do it using paste0

```
write.csv(output, paste0("C://Users/My Computer/dir", Sys.time(), ".csv"))
```

Is there a way to include system time in the file or is the user of these files better of finding a function to read these files by modification date ?

Comment: What error did you receive?  The paste0 function works for me.

Comment: I am getting this error
Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
  cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :
  cannot open file 'C://Users/My Computer/Documents/R/working/mining/2016-08-25 10:51:26.csv': Invalid argument

Comment: this works ok with Sys.Date but when using Sys.time the ":" character is introduced and this causes the error

Comment: Probably a Windows-specific problem. I can't reproduce the error on linux (ubuntu 16.04).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A work around is to format the system time differently. I got around this by replacing the ":" character with "."

```
write.csv(output, paste0("C://Users/My Computer/dir", format(Sys.time(), "%d-%b-%Y %H.%M"), ".csv"))
```